# PayPal webview not mobile friendly for Classic API

Tags: android, paypal, webview, uiwebview, paypal-adaptive-payments

I am using [Adaptive Payments API](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/products/adaptive-payments/) in my mobile app.  When you use this in a webview on `Android` or `iOS` it is not mobile friendly so you have to zoom in to see it.  Is there another way to go about this?

I can't use the [REST API](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/overview/) because it doesn't offer Adaptive Payments.

The only thing I see that might work are [Embedded Payment Flows](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/ht_ap-embeddedPayment-curl-etc/) but I'm not sure if this works on mobile.

Comment: Are you working with parallel or chained?  Or why exactly do you need adaptive?

Comment: Working with chained.

Comment: I think Embedded Payment Flows are what I need unless someone else suggests something.  I will try it. https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/ht_ap-embeddedPayment-curl-etc/

Comment: Yup, you're on the right track.